# Textbox is empty get all the data through sql query and php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a scenario which is:

I have 3 fields,

1. TextBox for item Code
2. Field for to date
3. Field for from date

Now what I am trying to do is if a person enters the itemcode and dates he will get the data according to that particular item on the entered date. And this scenario is working fine.

The next one is that if a person doesn't enter the item code and only date he will get all the data between the entered dates. And I am unable to achieve this case.

I am writing the query which I am using. Please have a look and help me to resolve this.

```
 $query = "
SELECT f.Itemm_ID
     , ABS(SUM(f.Quantity)) AS ISSUE
  FROM stock AS f
 WHERE f.Type = 'issue'
   AND CASE WHEN '".$ItemCode."' =' '
 THEN f.Itemm_ID >= 0
 WHEN f.Itemm_ID = '".$ItemCode."' 
 THEN f.Itemm_ID = '".$ItemCode."' 
 ELSE 0
 END)
 AND DATE(f.CREATION_DATETIME) 
 BETWEEN '".$FromDate."' AND 
        '".$ToDate."'
 GROUP 
    BY f.Itemm_ID
 
 ";
```

**The language i am writing the code in is php and sql. $ItemCode is bascially the values i am getting from my text field and same for dates.**

Comment: you can use if and else statement that is item code is empty then run sql statement which only finds using date and else run normal code

Comment: did this too but the problem is that when i am not entering the item code it returns only one row whereas i have 4 items in database

Comment: And see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: @smartF while printing in web are you using loop??

Comment: @Glossy Power i have done it. actually there was an issue my loop. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

No need to use case in this senerio you can query according to your need make itemcode optional in query like

```
$optionalCase = '';
        if (isset($ItemCode) && !empty($ItemCode)) {
            $optionalCase = "AND itemCode = '$ItemCode'";
        }

        $query = "SELECT f.`Itemm_ID`, ABS(SUM(f.`Quantity`)) AS ISSUE FROM stock AS f  WHERE f.`Type`='issue' AND DATE(f.`CREATION_DATETIME`) BETWEEN '" . $FromDate . "' AND '" . $ToDate . "' $optionalCase GROUP BY f.`Itemm_ID` ";
```

Comment: When i am not entering the itemcode it returns only one item where as i have 4 items in my database

Comment: Please don't promote insecure coding practices.